# unexpected end of file while using xml to list android

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I face a lot of problems in that project since I'm a junior.
Problem:
I'm sending data to remote host and receiving xml data but all I received is unexpected end of file:

#### Error

```
01-28 10:20:51.010: W/System.err(8285): org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected end of document
01-28 10:20:51.010: W/System.err(8285):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:125)
01-28 10:20:51.010: W/System.err(8285):     at com.Troid.utils.ServerApi.xmlToList(ServerApi.java:87)
01-28 10:20:51.010: W/System.err(8285):     at com.Troid.utils.ServerApi$1.run(ServerApi.java:158)
01-28 10:20:51.010: W/System.err(8285):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

#### xmlToList Function

```
public static List < String > xmlToList(InputStream src) throws Exception {
    LinkedList < String > result = new LinkedList < String > ();
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
    dbf.setValidating(false);
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(src));
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("string");
    if (int i = 0; i >= nl.getLength(); i++) {

        Node n = nl.item(i).getFirstChild();
        if (n == null) {
            result.add("");
        }
        result.add(n.getNodeValue());

    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Its totally well formed

Comment: There is nothing in your code that sends a file. Nor code that receives a file. Nor code that provokes that error. So where are you talking about?

Comment: I had a similar error. In my case the XML I was trying to read had a DOCTYPE tag but the SYSTEM url for the DOCTYPE was a broken link, so I assume Java got confused parsing the xml. You might want to look at the DOCTYPE tag in the xml response and see what's going on there.